# Regex.Replace is not working with separators

Tags: c#, regex

I just want to replace with `String.Empty` if any Separators found in a given string.

```
class Program
{
    private const string Separators = "-(). ";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var number = Format("88 88-88)8.8(88");
    }

    public static string Format(string number)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(number, Separators, string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Expected is : `8888888888` But was `88 88-88)8.8(88`. 
Did i miss something here.

**Edit**: if use

`Separators.ToCharArray().ToList().ForEach(c => { number = number.Replace(c.ToString(), string.Empty);});`

it works. But it could be better if i achieve with `Regex.Replace`.

Comment: Wouldn't be `String.Replace`?

Comment: in regex a dash means a range

Comment: `string Separators = "[\-\(\)\. ]"`

Comment: @rtpHarry a dash only signals a range when it is between `[]` *and* not the first or last character (and not escaped, of course).

Comment: @rtpHarry, Thanks for solution it is working fine with Separators = @"[\-()\. ]";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using a regular expression some characters have certain meanings. A dot means "any character", a dash means a range as in 0-9. I've escaped the characters and put them in a character set [] which means "any one in this set". I also renamed your `Separators` variable to better reflect what it is now.

Try this instead:

```
class Program
{
    private const string SeparatorsRegex = @"[\-()\. ]";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var number = Format("88 88-88)8.8(88");
    }

    public static string Format(string number)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(number, SeparatorsRegex, string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Tested it in Expresso and this worked as expected. Its a great tool for regex dev:

- http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm

(Ignore the terrible site design, it is a good util honest :P )

A further note, is that if you just want to strip everything that isnt a number then you could actually use this:

```
class Program
{
    private const string StripNonNumbersRegex = @"[^\d]";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var number = Format("88 88-88)8.8(88");
    }

    public static string Format(string number)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(number, StripNonNumbersRegex, string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks to whoever suggested the @ before the regex string, I've added it in.

Comment: @rptHarry, private const string SeparatorsRegex = @"[-(). ]"; is working fine. without \

Comment: Prasad,  the \ just escapes it. I would put it in there if I were you as it wont do any harm but not having it could do. If in the future you add something to the start it will become a range (from new character to ( on the ascii index).

Answer (score 1):

[Regex.Replace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx) works on patterns, not separators. You are confusing it with [String.Replace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx).

String.Replace(source, "-", string.empty) will work, but you will need to run this once per character.
Regex.Replace(source, pattern, string.empty) will work better, but you need to use a [RegEx pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx), not simple list the characters.

Comment: I am not confused.. how can achieve with Regex.Replace() using pattern with similar code.

Comment: Well do a test to see if he is right. Replace what you've got with a `string.Replace` instead. You'll soon find out who's right here.

Comment: `String.Replace()` wouldnt work here either - it would only match an occurrence of every seperator

Comment: Run String.Replace for each character or write a RegEx pattern.